# How to set from address while sending an email dynamically

Tags: organization-wide

I have a custom button on lead detail page which will redirect me to the send an email page(salesforce standard page for sending email). Now based on the lead brand(picklist which contains sony and samsung) , it should send an email. If it is sony , from address should be "aaa@aaa.com" and if it is brand samsung the from address should be "bbb@bbb.com". These two email address are already declared in OWD. Only by using configuration , can we do this ? Or we need to use SingleEmailMessageClass provided by salesforce(designing a vf page same as the standard email sending page).
Please help me out !! Its urgent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to the custom code the following parameter (&p26):

```
&p26={!IF(Lead brand = "Sony","aaa@aaa.com","bbb@bbb.com")}
```

Comment: thanks Ratan !! Even the from is populated, in the mail which i received is having from address of the current user who is logged in. But it has to be the populated from address.

Comment: @uma451 tis answer is posted by Lihod not me.. my answer is another one.